# Android Intent Button NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm trying have a button start another class. I get a null pointer exception which I found using logcat and I don't know why.

```java
    package com.Juggle2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Juggle2 extends Activity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Juggle2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  


            Button StartGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartGame);
            StartGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Juggle2.this, StartGame.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

And my XML manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.Juggle2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Juggle2"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <activity android:name=".Panel"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the log

```
    05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Juggle2/com.Juggle2.Juggle2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at com.Juggle2.Juggle2.onCreate(Juggle2.java:24)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
05-27 21:12:07.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6705):     ... 11 more
```

And inside the main.xml:

There is this button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/StartGame"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/startgame_button"
>
```

Comment: how does the exception look, and which line does it refer to?

Comment: Can you please post that logcat?

Comment: The exception here is important but without more information, I would speculate that there's a problem in your Panel.class's onCreate().

Comment: The error is definitely not in the Panel class. It is in the Juggle2 class. Your Panel class doesn't need an onCreate() unless it is an Activity.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be declared as an Activity in your manifest file. Create a new class that is an Activity (maybe call it PanelActivity), then call setContentView(new Panel()); in the onCreate() of PanelActivity. Don't forget to change the manifest file accordingly.

Comment: Also, obviously, change your intent to move to the PanelActivity class.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. How do I give you credit for this?

Comment: Click the check mark next to my answer to accept it. Glad I could help, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you! And may I say, you guys are fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel class is not an Activity but a SurfaceView. So, create a new Activity class (maybe called PanelActivity) and in its onCreate() call `setContentView(new Panel());`

Also, this line:
`Intent i = new Intent().setClass(Juggle2.this, Panel.class );`
Should look like:
`Intent i = new Intent(Juggle2.this, PanelActivity.class);`

Comment: Are you sure that your java code is exactly what you have in your question? Because logcat says the error is on line 30 and I only count 28 lines in your question.

Comment: Whatever is throwing the null pointer is happening immediately AFTER your button's onClickListener. (assuming your code is the same)

Comment: I deleted a few lines worth of debugging lines

Comment: Let me fix that.  Now it's at line 24